# Invalid values passed to methods with IntRange and NonNull don't abort a release build

Tags: android, gradle, lint

I'm reading https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html

In my example I use the annotations @NonNull, @IntegerRes, and @IntRange. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.maksim.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.IntRange;
import android.support.annotation.IntegerRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.StringRes;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("MyAnnotation", "" + getStr(null));
        setAlpha(12000);
        Log.d("MyAnnotation", "" + getRes(12));
    }

    public static boolean getStr(@NonNull String s) {
        return s.contains("a");
    }

    public static int getRes(@IntegerRes int s) {
        return s;
    }

    public void setAlpha(@IntRange(from=0,to=255) int alpha) {
        alpha *= 2;
        Log.d("MyAnnotation", "setAlpha=" + alpha);
    }
}
```

This is build.gradle of my module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.maksim.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

When I pass null to `getStr` or a integer out of [0, 255] to `setAlpha` and run `./gradlew app:assembleRelease`, it's built. However, the build fails when I call `getRes()` with an integer which is not a integer resource id.

So why doesn't it abort my build for @NonNull and @IntegerRes?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html)

For example, if a local variable that contains a null value is passed as a parameter to a method with the @NonNull annotation attached to that parameter, building the code ***generates a warning*** indicating a non-null conflict. On the other hand, attempting to reference the result of a method marked by @Nullable without first checking if the result is null ***generates a nullness warning***. You should only use @Nullable on a method's return value if every use of the method should be explicitly null-checked.

It is supposed to just

> generate a warning